# How to add a context menu in the webbrowser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I know there is already a thread relating to this, but i need more information. At the moment, i have this code which i got form the other thread,

```
    public void AttachContextMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            if (webTab1.IsScriptEnabled)
            {
                webTab1.InvokeScript("execScript", "function FindParentLink(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentLink(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction FindParentImage(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentImage(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction HandleContextMenu() \r\n{\r\n\tvar linkItem = FindParentLink(event.srcElement);\r\n    var imageItem = FindParentImage(event.srcElement);\r\n    var notifyOutput = '';\r\n    if (linkItem != null) if (linkItem.href != null) notifyOutput += linkItem.href;\r\n    if (imageItem != null) if (imageItem.src != null) notifyOutput += imageItem.src;\r\n    if (notifyOutput != '')\r\n        window.external.notify(notifyOutput);\r\n    else\r\n\t\twindow.external.notify('NOTLINKIMG');\r\n}");
                webTab1.InvokeScript("execScript", "document.oncontextmenu = HandleContextMenu;");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

The thread said that when the browser has finished loading you just call this method, although it doesnt seem to work.

Any Ideas on how i can get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows Phone 7.X only. not 8.

```
AddHandler wb.Loaded, Sub(sendr As Object, ev As EventArgs)
    wb.IsScriptEnabled = True
    AttachContextMenu()
End Sub
AddHandler wb.ScriptNotify, Sub(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NotifyEventArgs)
    Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

If you know how to open a context menu in WP8 WebBrowser control, please let us all know.
On WP8, I did it using the onmousedown event, a timer and the onmouseout event in combination with the findparentlink function from WP7.